# Unable to deploy node app to Heroku thru Github - does not run npm build

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, web-deployment

I have a project that I am trying to deploy on Heroku thru the source files on github, but it fails to "build" the project, instead it runs npm start (as far as I can understand).

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "workout-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Work out builder",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "start-dev": "npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "webpack -p && node server.js" 
  },
  "author": "Levon Saiyan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "npm": "^6.14.8",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

// the __dirname is the current directory from where the script is running
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

// send the user to index html page inspite of the url
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
```

On heroku, this is the error I get:

```
2020-11-09T17:52:31.135227+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=newnameworkout.herokuapp.com request_id=83df8e1d-d909-4b97-a768-f03297b67c71 fwd="136.34.60.0" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I've looked they everything online and tried everything, but I always get this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using * in that get method?

Answer (score 0):

On looking at your package.json, It looks like you have imported all your dependencies in devDependencis. Try moving that under dependencies.

If that dosen't help, Try using Procfile if you have not used.

Create a file named Procfile in the app's root directory without any file extension.

> start:node server.js

Enter the above line in Procfile and try deploying your application in Heroku through github.

[Refer this link for further details on Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format)

Comment: I made the dependency changes and still nothing. The procfile didn't really help either; it looks like it was getting stuck listening to the port (per the server.js file). I removed that reference from the package.json file and it was able to sucessfully build and deploy but still says the app crashed. I get this new error instead:

2020-11-10T00:35:13.880150+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"